# Wierd view on template For a time series line chart in highchart-angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

the highchart is updating but the legends of previous call is not destroyed in highchart when we try to update the view on highchart dynamically.
Here are the template:
you can see the data which is getting updated is 14 record and its showing succesfully but in the secord scenario the data which should be marked is only for 3 records here if you see it is overiding the previous 3 records and remaining 11 records remains the same. which is not a expected behaviour.

[you can see the data which is getting updated is 14 record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de9Dt.png)

[but in the secord scenario the data which should be marked is only for 3 records here if you see it is overiding the previous 3 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14LtP.png)

[Code subscribig to http call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10eBZ.png)

[Sending Data for modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtTmS.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome! Please check [ask] and provide a [mcve] as **code blocks** in your question, not images.

Comment: At our official Highcharts angular wrapper you will find examples that you can use like template. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#online-examples